# How FEC works on GNU Radio

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I am new to GNU Radio.

I need some reference to how to use FEC block in GNURadio.

When I try to make encoder and decoder without modulation, its work as well, but when I using modulation and add some noise, there is a problem.

Received bit are not same with transmitted bit and make a decoder not working as well. Say I have k=40 bit and encoded c=64 bit ready to transmit, but I receive extra bit c=96 bit, so decoder can't recognize and decode all c received data as **zeros**. Find pictures of my simulation system below.

[TX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVHqu.png)
[RX+Noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5J93.png)
[Python_read_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL1Ae.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please embedd the images into your post (instead of links.) Not everyone can open outside links. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is a how you can embed the images in a post.